# How do I stop an echo from displaying the same thing twice?

Tags: php, html

I have a function that displays a few divs running through a loop using echo but when i put the function in it shows the info where i want it in the table cell but also next to the table

Here is my code

```
function getTestRows($appName)
{
    $implodeArray =array();
    $testsql = "SELECT DISTINCT app_instance_name FROM application_instances WHERE application_name ='$appName' AND environment = 'test' ";
    $testres = mysql_query($testsql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($testres) >=1)
    {
        while($test = mysql_fetch_array($testres))
        {
            echo("<div>".$test['app_instance_name']."</div>");
        }
    }
    else
    {
         echo("<span>No results found</span>");
    }
}
```

and the echo that displays it...

```
echo("<table id='ver-zebra' style='display: inline-table;'>
<colgroup>
    <col class='vzebra-odd' />
    <col class='vzebra-even'/>
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <th id='appNameHead' OnMouseOver=\"this.style.cursor='pointer';\"  onclick=\"openIndiv('$tmp[0]');\">
        $tmp[0]
    </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope='col' id='test'>
        Test
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>
<div style='width: 300px; height: 100px; overflow: auto;'>");
getTestRows($tmp[0]);
echo("</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that this function is only getting called once?

Comment: what's the code before the first echo you've shown us? Given the HTML, the output and what I'm seeing, the `getTestRows()` is getting called before the code you've posted.

Comment: This article might be useful for you: [When Flat PHP meets Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html) - it shows how you can de-couple data management and output from each other easily which will help you to prevent such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call echo, it immediately gets put into the response.  Have `getTestRows()` return a String which is your HTML instead:

```
function getTestRows($appName)
{
    $ret = '';
    $implodeArray =array();
    $testsql = "SELECT DISTINCT app_instance_name FROM application_instances WHERE application_name ='$appName' AND environment = 'test' ";
    $testres = mysql_query($testsql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($testres) >=1)
    {
        while($test = mysql_fetch_array($testres))
        {
            $ret .= "<div>".$test['app_instance_name']."</div>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
         $ret .= "<span>No results found</span>";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: ...or rename it to `printTestRows()`

Comment: @Chris:  that still won't change it's functionality.

Comment: yes, but it makes it readable. I was emphasizing that it says "get" but clearly does a "print". Consistency, gotta get me somma that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't output big chunks of text with echo (or print). It's far easier to just drop out of PHP mode (`?>`) and output raw HTML instead. If you HAVE to do big chunks of text while in PHP, at least use a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc). They act exactly like a double-quoted string, but don't use quotes as delimiters, so you don't have to escape anything EXCEPT `$` signs when you don't want them seen as variables.